# Find P^(-1)*BP without computing P^(-1)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

**What I have:**

Eigenvalues: $-1$ and $0$

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\-2&-2&-1\\0&0&-1\end{bmatrix} \;\;\text{ and }\;\;P = \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\-2&0&-1\\0&-2&0\end{bmatrix}.$$

I know that $$P^{-1}BP = D  \implies  BP = DP$$

**Question:**

How can I find $P^{1}BP$ without computing $P^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we can find the characteristic polynomial of the matrix $B$ to find its eigenvalues. So we get $$\det\pmatrix{\lambda - 1 & -1 & -1\\2 & \lambda + 2 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &\lambda+1} = -\lambda(\lambda+1)^2 =0 \implies \lambda = 0, -1.$$ So we have that the multiplicity of $-1$ is two. We can use these eigenvalues to find the *eigenvectors* of $B$. Skipping some work, we find out that our eigenpairs are $$\left(-1,\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\\2\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}\right), \left(0,\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right).$$ Because our $3\times3$ matrix has $3$ linearly independent eigenvectors, it is thus diagonalizable and hence get a diagonal matrix $D$. So, we put our eigenvalues in the same order on the main diagonal that the column eigenvectors appear in $P$ and we've thus found our solution without finding the inverse of $P$: $$P^{-1}BP = \pmatrix{-1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &-1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0}.$$

Comment: Wow, this is a perfect explanation. I could not find this anywhere, thank you so much!